# Spotfire: calculate the frequency of value pairs in a column

Tags: frequency, spotfire

I have the following table in Spotfire:

```
ID  Rule  
1   a  
1   b  
1   a  
1   c  
2   a  
2   a  
3   a  
3   a  
3   b  
4   b  
4   c  
5   c
```

I need to calculate how many times each rule appears with each other rule. 
The result from this table should be:

```
Couple  Occurrences  
a-b     2            (Explanation: from ID 1 and ID 3)  
a-c     1            (Explanation: from ID 1)  
b-c     2            (Explanation: from ID 1 and ID 4)
```

or something like this:

```
   a   b   c
a  3   2   1
b  2   3   2
c  1   2   3
```

(and I will ignore a-a, b-b and c-c).

I don't know how to obtain this in Spotfire without adding too many columns (there are 21 millions of rows and 60 different rules, so I don't want to increase too much the dimensions of this file).

Do you know what can I do? I imagine I will have to use a script but I don't know how to build it.

Thank you!

Valentina

Comment: Have you tried placing the rule column on the category and value axis of a cross table? It seems to be just what you want.

Comment: Yes, but it shows me only the values along the diagonal (a-a, b-b, c-c), the other values are zero. I don't know if, through a modification of the cross table, I could obtain what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem using

```
Rank = DenseRank([row],[data],[ID])
```

("data" is an additional variable I have in my data)

```
Concatenate = UniqueConcatenate([Rule]) OVER (Intersect(AllNext([rank]),[ID],[data]))
```

and then taking the combinations where [rank] = 1. 
It's not a perfect solution because I don't obtain value pairs but I obtain every combination of rules I can find in my data.

I am still interested in a better solution, but maybe someone could find this answer useful.

Thank you,

Valentina